# Check wpf textbox focus

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

In my `Textbox`, I've set `Textbox.MaxLength = 2`. What I want to achieve is when I enter "6" in my `Textbox`, if the focus of the `Textbox` is lost, the value will become "06".

```
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox.Text)))
        {
            //Minute value cannot be more than 59
            if (Int32.Parse(Textbox.Text) > 59)
                Textbox.Text = string.Empty;

            else if (Int32.Parse(Textbox.Text) < 10 && Textbox.IsFocused == false)
                Textbox.Text = Int32.Parse(Text.Text).ToString("00");
        }
```

I've tried to set `Texbox.IsFocused == false`, but it still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: In which event you added this code/

Comment: @Sajeetharan, is PreviewKeyDown.

Comment: Handle LostKeyboardFocus event. PreviewKeyDown is for checking before displaying something in the TextBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use LostFocus event.

xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbTextBox" Height="30" LostFocus="tbTextBox_LostFocus"/>
```

code behind

```
private void tbTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tbTextBox.Text = tbTextBox.IsFocused.ToString();
}
```